# Obtain USB device hub and port location property

Tags: c#, c++

When looking under device manager at a network adapter settings, the `general` tab displays a `location` property such as `Port_#0004.Hub_#0005`.

How would I go about retreiving this property in either C# or C++?

Comment: Just a warning, the Location string has completely different content in different versions of Windows.

Comment: I was unaware of that fact, so thank you for the warning.  I shall have to look for another method to determine the connection location of a device it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty function with SPDRP_LOCATION_INFORMATION as Property.